# Radio Button Will only reflect after two clicks

Tags: magento2, javascript, checkbox, react-js

We are using an RMA module which let the customer select a new return for their purchased item. When clicking on the item radio to select an item it should bring up the entire information on the specific item, However in our case the customer clicks to check the radio once, Radio is checked but not reflected or bringing the item's information. Second click on the checked radio now brings the item's information and let the customer proceed with the return. The questions is how do we fix this so that customers needs to click just once on the radio in order to proceed and not twice?
attached are two images. 1 image shows that customer clicked one and the radion is checked but nothing came up, Second image shows the second click that shows the entire information for the item and let's continue.

[image]

[image]

```
  <script>
      window.rmaDataConfig = <?= /* @noEscape */ \Zend_Json::encode($block->getRmaConfigData()); ?>;
  </script>
<div class="block">
    <div class="block-content">
    <form class="form"
        method="post"
        action="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getUrl('rmasystem/newrma/saverma/', ['_secure' => $block->getRequest()->isSecure()]); ?>"
        enctype="multipart/form-data" id="save_rma_form" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
        <div id="new-rma-component" data-bind="scope:'new-rma-component'" class="field">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "#new-rma-component": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app":  <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout();?>
                }
            }
            </script>
            <div class="clear"></div>
                      <input type="hidden" value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFormKey() ?>" name="form_key"/>
                      <fieldset class="fieldset login" data-hasrequired="<?= /* @noEscape */ __('* Required Fields') ?>">
                        <!-- ko if: empty() == 1  -->
                        <div class="field wk-noitem no-display" data-bind="css: {'no-display': !empty()}">
                            <tr>
                                <td><?= /* @noEscape */ __('No item applicable for RMA generation.') ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko if: itemDetails().length > 0  -->
                        <div class="field">
                        </div>
                          <div class="field required account">
                              <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Items Ordered"); ?>:</span></label>
                              <div class="control table-wrapper rma-order-items">
                                  <table name="items" class="data table ko-grid" id="wk_rma_order_details">
                                      <thead>
                                          <tr>
                                              <th scope="col" class="col rma-select"><input data-bind="checked: checkAll" type="checkbox" class="wk-option-input" id="all_select"/></th>
                                              <th scope="col" class="col name" title="Product Name"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Name"); ?></th>
                                              <th scope="col" class="col sku" title="Product SKU"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("SKU"); ?></th>
                                              
                                              <th scope="col" class="col qty" title="Product Quantity Ordered"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Qty"); ?></th>
                                              <th scope="col" class="col price" title="Product Price"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Price"); ?></th>
                                              <th scope="col" class="col rt-qty" title="Product Quantity Returning"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Return Qty"); ?></th>
                                              <th scope="col" class="col reason" title="Reason"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Reason"); ?></th>

                                          </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'orderdetails-template', foreach: itemDetails }">
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- /ko -->
                          
                        <script type="text/html" id="orderdetails-template">
                          <tr>

                            <!-- ko if: error === false -->
                            <!-- ko if: disabled === false -->
                                <td data-th="Select Item" class="col rma-select" class='wk_rma_check'>
                                  <input data-bind="value: itemid, checked: isSlected, attr: {'data-value': product_id, 'data-product_type': product_type,'name': 'item_checked['+itemid+']'}" type='checkbox' class='wk_rma_pro_check wk-option-input'/>
                                </td>
                              <!-- /ko -->
                              <!-- ko if: disabled === true -->
                                <td data-th="Select Item" class="col rma-select" class='wk_rma_check'></td>
                              <!-- /ko -->
                              <td data-th="Item Name" class="col name">
                                <div class="wk-pro-divide1">
                                  <img data-bind="attr: {'src': image}" style="float:left;margin-right:10px;" class="image" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="wk-pro-divide1">
                                  <a target='_blank' data-bind="attr: {'href':url}, text: name"></a>
                                </div>
                              </td>
                              <td data-th="Item SKU" class="col sku" data-bind="text: sku"></td>

                              <td data-th="Item Qty" class="col qty" data-bind="text: qty"></td>
                              <td data-th="Item Price" class="col price" data-bind="html: price" class='item_price'></td>
                              <!-- ko if: disabled === false -->
                                    <td data-th="Returning Qty" class="col rt-qty" class='a-right'><input type='number' data-bind="attr: {'name': 'return_item['+itemid+']', 'max':qty, 'min': 1, 'id': 'qty_'+itemid}" class='return_item'/></td>
                                    <td data-th="Reason" class="col reason">
                                        <select class='select item_reason' data-bind="attr: {'name': 'item_reason['+itemid+']', 'id': 'reason_'+itemid}">
                                            <option value=''><?= /* @noEscape */ __('Select Reason') ?></option>
                                            <?php $reason_coll = $block->getRegionCollection();
                                            foreach ($reason_coll as $reason): ?>
                                                    <option value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $reason->getId()?>"><?= /* @noEscape */ $reason->getReason(); ?></option>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                              <!-- /ko -->
                              <!-- ko if: disabled === true -->
                                  <td class="return-filled" colspan="2"><?= /* @noEscape */ __('Return Request Already Sent.'); ?></td>
                              <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: error === true -->
                              <td colspan='7'><?= /* @noEscape */ __('No order selected') ?></td>
                            <!-- /ko -->

                          </tr>
                        </script>
                        <div class="field image-field">
                        </div>
                        <div class="field image-field">
                            <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Related Images"); ?>:</span></label>
                            <button type="button" for="related_images" id="wk_rma_label_image" class="rma-image-button" data-bind="click: addImageBlock">
                                <span id="wk_rma_upload_icon"></span>
                                <span id="wk_rma_upload_text"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Add Images"); ?></span>
                            </button>
                            <input type="hidden" name="total_images" data-bind="value: totalImages"/>
                            <div class="control" id="image_block">
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/html" id="rmaImageTemplate">
                            <div class="wk-showcase-block">
                                <div title="Delete Showcase" class="wk-delete-item" data-bind="click: deleteImage">x</div>
                                <div class="wk-default-block"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Add Image") ?></div>
                                <input type="file" name="related_images[]" accept="image/*" class="wk-showcase-img wk-no-display" data-bind="event:{change: fileSelect}">
                            </div>
                            </script>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field required clear-section wk-delivery">
                            <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Product Delivery Status"); ?>:</span></label>
                            <div class="control">
                            <div class="control">
                                <select class="required-entry select"
                                        id="customer_delivery_status"
                                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                                        name="customer_delivery_status"
                                        data-bind="options: deliveryStatus,
                                            optionsText: 'label',
                                            optionsValue: 'value',
                                            value: selectedDelivery,
                                            optionsCaption: 'Select Delivery Status'"
                                        >
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <!-- ko if: selectedDelivery() == 1 -->
                              <div class="field required clear-section">
                                  <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Package Condition"); ?>:</span></label>
                                  <div class="control">
                                      <select class="required-entry select" data-validate="{required:true}" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ __('Select Package Condition'); ?>" name="package_condition">
                                          <option value=""><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Select Package Condition"); ?></option>
                                          <option value="0"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Open"); ?></option>
                                          <option value="1"><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Packed"); ?></option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="field required">
                                <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Enter Consignment Number"); ?>:</span></label>
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input id="wk_rma_consignment_no" type="text" name="customer_consignment_no" data-validate="{required:true}" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                          <div class="field required clear-section">
                              <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Resolution Type"); ?>:</span></label>
                              <div class="control">
                                <select class="required-entry select"
                                        id="resolution_type"
                                        data-validate="{required:true}"
                                        name="resolution_type"
                                        data-bind="options: resolutionType,
                                         optionsText: 'label',
                                         optionsValue: 'value',
                                         optionsCaption: 'Select Resolution Type'"
                                        >
                                </select>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="field">
                              <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Additional Information"); ?>:</span></label>
                              <div class="control">
                                  <textarea name="additional_info" id="wk_rma_additional_info"></textarea>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('rma.newrma.customfield') ?>
                          <div class="field">
                              <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Return Policy"); ?>:</span></label>
                              <div class="control">
                                  <div id="wk_rma_agreement_cntnt"><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getPolicy(); ?></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="field required">
                              <input name="agree" id="wk_i_agree" type="checkbox" class="wk_rma_checkall" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
                              <label class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("I Agree"); ?>:</span></label>
                         </div>
                    <div class="buttons-set actions-toolbar">
                        <div class="primary">
                            <button id="wk_rma_button_submit" class="action save primary" title="<?= /* @noEscape */ __('Submit Request'); ?>" type="submit" data-bind="event: {click: saveRma}">
                                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ __("Submit Request"); ?></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  <a href="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getUrl('rmasystem/index', ['_secure' => $block->getRequest()->isSecure()])?>">&laquo;<?= /* @noEscape */ __("back"); ?></a>
              </fieldset>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage'
    ], function($){

        var dataForm = $('#save_rma_form');
        dataForm.mage('validation', {});
            
        $('body').on('click','#wk_rma_button_submit', function() {
            if (dataForm.valid()!=false) {
                $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
        var rma_prod = [];
        $('body').on('click','.wk_rma_pro_check',function(){
            let rma_product_type = $(this).data('product_type');
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                rma_prod.push(rma_product_type);
            }else{
                var i = rma_prod.indexOf(rma_product_type);
                if(i != -1) {
                    rma_prod.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
            if(rma_prod.indexOf("simple") > -1 ||  rma_prod.indexOf("configurable") > -1) {
                $('.wk-delivery').css('display','block');
            } else {
                $('.wk-delivery').css('display','none');
            }
        });
       
        $('body').on('click','#all_select',function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $('.wk_rma_pro_check').each(function(){
                   var product_type =  $(this).data('product_type');
                   rma_prod.push(product_type);
                });
                if(rma_prod.indexOf("simple") > -1 ||  rma_prod.indexOf("configurable") > -1) {
                    $('.wk-delivery').css('display','block');
                } else {
                    $('.wk-delivery').css('display','none');
                }
            } else {
                rma_prod = [];
                $('.wk-delivery').css('display','block');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<script>
    require([
        'mage/url',
        'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
    ], function(url, blockLoader) {
        blockLoader("<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>");
        return url.setBaseUrl('<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBaseUrl() ?>');
    })
</script>
```